# Push changes to data in one Django model to another

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I writing an application that has a change control workflow.  Users retrieve data for a particular month and then they make edits to it and there is a review phase where they can approve records.  There are 2 identical tables a master and a staging table.  When the user loads up the application they load data from the master table and can edit it in a crud grid.  When they hit the stage button I want that data to get pushed inserted into the staging table.  How do i tell my view to do that.  The staging table doesnt have the associated records yet, i want the records that are sent back as part of the push  to get inserted there rather than doing an update to the master table?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to store every changed field into stating table and your master table contains original copy, am i right ?

Comment: Correct.  how would i do this.  eventually after the changes are approved in the staging table i want them merged back into master @MuhammadFaizanFareed

Comment: The tables have the same schema, just different names

Answer (score 0):

You can add new field name can be status in your master table which shows this record in staging process.

For example : 
You inserted new record into master table so initial value of status will be 1 (new_created).

When you want to process Master table record you must change the status to 2 (in_staging) which is showing thia record in already in staging process can't process further. 
Using new field can manage your process easily and you can check how many records are in staging process at a given time.
When you store the master record you can check which fields are changed or not in form.

Save master record with status 2 and copy the master record and save them into staging table.

After that when your staging completed you can use the same process to save your objects.